# Does it break MVVM design principles when you dynamically create controls?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I feel like the question is mostly in the title, but to go more in depth:

My manager is really pushing MVVM in all of our WPF apps, but today I was asked to dynamically create certain controls in order to achieve a more generic solution to a problem.  For some reason this seems contradictory to the MVVM patterns he preaches.  The whole idea is to separate the View from the Model right?  Or am I missing something here?

Any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: It depends. Your question is quite general. If you could generate these controls in Datatemplate and use ViewModel to drive them, then you could move the logic into MVVM. However sometimes UI is quite complex and we do not have to follow every part into MVVM.

Comment: I do believe that creating controls in code is against "the WPF way" (what's the need? `DataTemplateSelector` and triggers not good enough?), but you cannot say that it is contradictory to MVVM without qualification. Suppose the view decides to add some controls to itself and bind them to the viewmodel, just as if they had been created from XAML. How is that subverting MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create dynamic controls driven by the View Model. WPF has some powerful concepts of Templates. Read up on the following a little bit
DataTemplate, ContentControl, ItemsControl.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's contradictory. If you do MVVM, there's NO reason to create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code.

WPF provides several mechanisms to create "dynamic" UIs without having to resort to the code-behind approaches of UI frameworks such as winforms.

- DataTemplates.
- ItemsControls.

Post some sample of what you're trying to do and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Your first para talks about MVVM, while the rest switches to talking about WPF in general. I do agree with the latter part (although the wording is perhaps too aggressive), but how is MVVM connected to that?

Comment: @Jon There's no "MVVM in general". MVVM was specifically made for WPF, then ported as a philosophy / pattern to other technologies. My appreciations of MVVM from a WPF point of view and WPF from an MVVM point of view are logical.